# WordPress Reply button?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using WordPress version 3.3.1, and I used `wp_list_comments()` for the comment section. There's <kbd>Reply</kbd> buttons on every post, which is created automatically. But however when I click on them, it reloads the page and nothing happens. Am I missing something? (It said `addComment is not defined` in the Developer tools)

Page: [`http://derek1906.site50.net/blog/?p=11`](http://derek1906.site50.net/blog/?p=11)

Comment: what you expecting? You want to open an inline comment box when user click on the *reply* button

Comment: Something like when the user clicks on reply, then the "leave a comment" part should goes up.

Comment: i am not sure that can happen, but its possible to create a comment box which appears when user click on the reply button.

Comment: Yes, something like that is acceptable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was what i have done for my theme.When user click on the reply button an inline comment box appears with cancel button and user have the choice to submit the comment or reply to a comment.

```
<?php // Do not delete these lines
    if ('comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
        die ('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!');
    if (!empty($post->post_password)) { // if there's a password
        if ($_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH] != $post->post_password) {  // and it doesn't match the cookie
            ?>
            <p class="nocomments">This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments.</p>
            <?php
            return;
        }}?>
<!-- You can start editing here. -->
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
<h3 id="comments"><?php comments_number('No Responses', 'One Response', '% Responses' );?> to &#8220;<?php the_title(); ?>&#8221;</h3>
<ol class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments('callback=advanced_comment_custmization'); ?>
</ol>
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_comments_link() ?></div>
    <div class="alignright"><?php next_comments_link() ?></div>
</div>
<?php else : // this is displayed if there are no comments so far ?>
<?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
<!-- If comments are open, but there are no comments. -->

<?php else : // comments are closed ?>
<!-- If comments are closed. -->
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
<?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
<div id="respond">
 <h3><?php comment_form_title( 'Leave a Reply', 'Leave a Reply to %s' ); ?></h3>
 <div class="cancel-comment-reply">
 <small><?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?></small>
</div>
  <?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !$user_ID ) : ?>
        <p>You must be <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>">logged in</a> to post a comment.</p>
<?php else : ?>
<form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">
 <div id="inputArea">
 <?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>
 <p>Logged in as <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="Log out of this account">Log out &raquo;</a></p>
 <?php else : ?>
<input type="text" name="author" id="c_author" value="<?php echo $comment_author; ?>" size="22" tabindex="1" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?> />
<label for="author"><small>Name <?php if ($req) echo "(required)"; ?></small></label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="c_email" value="<?php echo $comment_author_email; ?>" size="22" tabindex="2" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?> />
<label for="email"><small>Mail (will not be published) <?php if ($req) echo "(required)"; ?></small></label>
<input type="text" name="url" id="c_url" value="<?php echo $comment_author_url; ?>" size="22" tabindex="3" />
<label for="url"><small>Website</small></label>
<?php endif; ?>
<!--<p><small><strong>XHTML:</strong> You can use these tags: <code><?php echo allowed_tags(); ?></code></small></p>-->
<textarea name="comment" id="c_comment" cols="100%" rows="10" tabindex="4"></textarea>
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Submit Comment" />
 <?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
</div>
<?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
</form>
<div class="comment-rss"><?php comments_rss_link('Subscribe to Comments via RSS'); ?></div>
<?php endif; // If registration required and not logged in ?>
</div>
```

Code is quite simple and the part which is responsible for showing up the comment box inline will begin from  `<div id="inputArea">`.
Hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. p.s.: I found out that I can just use `<?php comment_form(); ?>` to create this whole thing. :D